# Add object to array with key

Tags: node.js

https://repl.it/repls/DeadlyRemarkableKeys

```
const test1 = {["123"]:{stuff: '123'}};
console.log(test1);

var test2 = [];
test2["123"] = {stuff: '123'};
console.log(test2);
```

I would like to get proper array with objects linked to keys, like in test2 variable, however written in style of test1 ? test1 results with test1[0][123], whereas I need test1[123].

Thank you

Comment: Don't use an array as the key? Also what you say you want is a number, not a string. It's unclear what you're after.

Comment: test1 is declared as an object and test2 as an array. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Please edit the question with clear details.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array as key of an object looks weird. 
Probably this is what you're looking for:

```
const test1 = {'123': {stuff: '123'}};
console.log(test1['123']); // prints {stuff: '123'};
```

Comment: If I append array with ... for some reason first key is [0][1] instead of ['123]?

Comment: How do you "append"?

Comment: const NewTest = {...test1 || [], {["123"]:{stuff: '123'}}, Keys are not right then

Comment: You're again using an array as key. What exactly are you trying to achieve?